# What is the fastest way to create a polygon of the part of PostGIS raster that is not filled with NoData values?

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, nodata

I have a raster table in PostGIS. For each row, I want to create a polygon that represents the part of the raster that is filled with data (not NODATA). I found out that ST_Polygon(rast) does the job. However, it works very very slowly.

Is there another solution for this problem that works faster?

Comment: did you compare with gdal_rasterize ?

Comment: I need it to be part of another query. So I cannot use gdal package I think.

Answer (score 1):

you could try with [ST_DumpAsPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html) (which uses gdal internally). To avoid making unnecessary polygons, make sure the you set a single value for each pixel that should end up in a polygon (e.g. with [ST_Reclass](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Reclass.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Would add this as a comment but don't have enough reputation. @radouxju's answer led me in the following direction:

```
select row_number() over () as rid, st_union((a.dump).geom) as geom
from (
    select st_dumpaspolygons(st_reclass(rast, 1, '(-10000000-10000000):1', '1BB', null)) as dump --assumes NODATA value has been assigned to raster
    from test_schema.raster
) as a
where (a.dump).val = 1;
```

I'm including my SQL since I struggled with a few things, e.g. ST_DumpAsPolygons returning a [composite data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html). I don't know if this is the fastest way, but it's fairly quick with my rasters. All credit to @radouxju.